# Django blog application error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have just started coding with Django module and for now I am just copying the code from Lynda. 
Although I coded correctly, I got tons of error when I tried to run the server.

I guess it is because of differences between Django 2 and Django 1.8.

What exactly should I change? You may find my code and errors below. Thanks.

Errors:

> python manage.py runserver
>
> Performing system checks...
>
> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x105a53598> Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py",
>   line 17, in include
>       urlconf_module, app_name = arg ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 121, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 364, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 351, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
>   line 73, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
>   line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
>       all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py",
>   line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
>       url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
>   line 36, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 536, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py",
>   line 36, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 529, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 22, in 
>       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),   File "/Users/keremkizbaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py",
>   line 27, in include
>       'provide the namespace argument to include() instead.' % len(arg) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to
>   include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of
>   patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include()
>   instead.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get.queryset().filter(status = 'published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique_for_date = 'publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE ,  related_name = 'blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'draft')

    objects = models.Manager() # the default manager
    published = PublishedManager() # the Dahl-specific manager.


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args = [self.publish__year,
                                                    self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                                    self.publosh.strftime('%d'),
                                                    self.slug])
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = post,
                                    status = 'published',
                                    publish__year = year,
                                    publish__month = month,
                                    publish__day = day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import url from . import views from django.contrib import admin



urlpatters = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name = 'post_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name = 'post_detail'), ]
```

URL.py 2:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls',namespace = 'blog', app_name = 'blog')),
]
```

Comment: The issue is with your urls.py....please post the same.

Comment: There's lots of differences between Django 1.8 and 2.0. If you use Django 2.0 with a tutorial written for 1.8, then you might hit several other problems like this. It would be better to use the same version of Django (although bear in mind Django 1.8 will only be supported for a few more months), or perhaps look for a different tutorial. You'd also have fewer problems if you used Django 1.11 (which is a long term support release).

Comment: I added urls.py to my main question. Thanks for help @Faizunnabi

Comment: Bro plz post the urls.py which is at the location mysite/mysite/

Comment: I added that one too, thanks @Faizunnabi

Comment: In your urls.py file in mysite/mysite replace with this
`url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)` .The reason is that `include(admin.site.urls)` returns 3-tuple which is not supported by the upper versions of Django.

Comment: I couldnt get it @Faizunnabi. What should my code exactly be?

Comment: In your mysite/mysite urls.py file replace the line url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) with url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)